PostgreSQL - select all anagrams with wildcard
I have a big table with words (let's call it words). It consists of three columns, eg.:
id, word, sorted_word
1 , dog , dgo
2 , god , dgo
3 , cat , act
etc.

To find anagrams of o word I can do a simple search by the sorted_word column: SELECT word FROM words WHERE sorted_word='dgo'.
But to find anagrams with wildcard (think of having a blank tile in Scrabble), I would have to add some OR logic. For example to find all anagrams from letters D, O, G and any other letter, I would have to make that query:
SELECT word FROM words WHERE sorted_word LIKE '_dgo' OR sorted_word LIKE 'd_go' OR sorted_word LIKE 'dg_o' OR sorted_word LIKE'dgo_';  


Is it possible to create index in PostgreSQL for such queries?
If SQL is not suitable for this kind of problem, what other database would be better?


Postgres supports regular expressions with the % operator.  No, you can't index expression-based queries.  Have you done any research on this?  There are lots of algorithms.

@TimRoberts For indexing you can use the extension pg_trgm, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-INDEX

For words of length 5 or more, you could use a trigram index:
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX ON words USING gin (sorted_word gin_trgm_ops)
   WHERE length(sorted_word) >= 5;

Then you could query like this:
SELECT word FROM words
WHERE sorted_word LIKE '_floo' AND length(sorted_word) >= 5
   OR sorted_word LIKE 'd_loo' AND length(sorted_word) >= 5
   OR sorted_word LIKE 'df_oo' AND length(sorted_word) >= 5
   OR sorted_word LIKE 'dfl_o' AND length(sorted_word) >= 5
   OR sorted_word LIKE 'dflo_' AND length(sorted_word) >= 5;

and the trigram index should speed up the search.
It appears that the middle pattern df_oo doesn't contain a trigram, but pg_trgm prepends two spaces to each word and appends one space, so there would be the trigrams   d,  df and oo , which together should be selective enough.
For shorter words an index won't help directly, but you can use a partial index to reduce the search space, and there are not so many short words anyway.
CREATE INDEX ON words (sorted_word) WHERE length(sorted_word) < 5;

Then search with
SELECT word FROM words
WHERE sorted_word LIKE '_foo' AND length(sorted_word) < 5
   OR sorted_word LIKE 'd_oo' AND length(sorted_word) < 5
   OR sorted_word LIKE 'df_o' AND length(sorted_word) < 5
   OR sorted_word LIKE 'dfo_' AND length(sorted_word) < 5;

